# How do you integrate flexbox with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flexbox

I would like to use flexbox with ruby on rails. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer is easy. For each element that you want to flex, you need to declare `display: flex`.  To avoid needing to use the custom browser commands e.g. `-webkit-box-orient`, include the [autoprefixer gem](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) so you can just enter standard flexbox commands into your css or scss files. Here is an example

```
.{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: centre
}
```

Comment: So, what is the gem "flexbox-rails" for, then?  https://github.com/woodcrust/flexbox-rails - Are you saying it is unnecessary to include this gem in your gemfile and add the include line to application.css?

Comment: Looking at the ```flexbox-rails``` wiki, it adds a number of wrapper classes for creating rows and columns.  This might be useful to you, but you do not need it to use standard flexbox instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a front end framework like [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html) to achieve this as well.  I am currently using their [rails gem](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails) and its working great in my app.